# How do I read and understand stacktraces?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, stack-trace

I have a few apps on the market and recently I have received a few error reports that give stacktraces. I don't quite understand how to read and understand them, so I can actually fix the issue.

Below is 1 of the traces:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.emsprotocols.nycemsprotocols/com.emsprotocols.nycemsprotocols.ConnectivitCheck}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at     com.emsprotocols.nycemsprotocols.ConnectivityCheck.onCreate(ConnectivityCheck.java:21)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
... 11 more
```

I am not sure if this is 1 error or 2 or even more. And I am not sure how to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application fails to load the activity `com.emsprotocols.nycemsprotocols.ConnectivitCheck` because of a NullPointerException:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.emsprotocols.nycemsprotocols/com.emsprotocols.nycemsprotocols.ConnectivitCheck}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

The exception is raised in the onCreate method in line 21:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   com.emsprotocols.nycemsprotocols.ConnectivityCheck.onCreate(ConnectivityCheck.java:21)

This is actualy one error, which is wrapped by another one (`NullPointerException` wrapped by `RuntimeException`)

Comment: Thank You. That seems simple enough, but what are the other items and numbers present?

Answer (score 3):

Debugging is about finding the cause, so look for this line:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at     com.emsprotocols.nycemsprotocols.ConnectivityCheck.onCreate(ConnectivityCheck.java:21)
```

And then look at line 21 of that file.  For a language without pointers, Java sure seems to get lots of null pointer exceptions.  What typically happens is that in the underlying implementation, objects become pointers to data structures.  When you call a method of an object, ie

```
myObject.spindle()
```

The VM follows the pointer that tracks myObject, expects to find a data structure, and expects to have one of the entires in that structure lead it to the code of a method called spindle().

The problem is that if myObject is null, then there actually is no data structure to look in for the spindle() method.  You've asked it to do the impossible - without exception handling, the program can't continue.

Most commonly, the reason why an object would be null is that you've assigned your object from something else, which was unable to give you one, and so returned null.

Fixing your problem generally follows one or more of three courses:

- Figure out why your object is null, and fix that
- Test that your object is not null before you try to call any of its method or access its fields
- Handle exceptions - ie, tell the program how to recover when it runs into this situation

Comment: Thank You. That seems simple enough, but what are the other items and numbers present?

Comment: It's a call stack - the history, in reverse order, of method invocations by which the program got to the point of the exception. So for example we see that your onCreate() method is called by something in the platform code called android.app.Activity.performCreate() which was in turn called by android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate() etc...

Answer (score 2):

Find you package name after `at`, here is

```
at     com.emsprotocols.nycemsprotocols.ConnectivityCheck.onCreate(ConnectivityCheck.java:21)
```

which means line 21 in `ConnectivityCheck.java` has a problem, try to fix it and go on.

Comment: Thank You. That seems simple enough, but what are the other items and numbers present?

Comment: As `stacktraces` means, this error cause its former functions fail. So while this item means an error in your package, the others means errors in their corresponding packages(the system's).